# How to load my Entity in Entity form

Tags: 8, entities

i have:

```
/**
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "my_entity",
 *   label = @Translation("drwywr werwer label"),
 *   bundle_label = @Translation("My entity type"),
 *   handlers = {
 *     bla...
 *     "form" = {
 *       "default" = "Drupal\my_entity\Form\MyEntityForm",
 *       "edit" = "Drupal\my_entity\Form\MyEntityForm",
 *       "delete" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityDeleteForm"
 *     },
 *     bla...
 *   },
 *   translatable = FALSE,
 *   entity_keys = { bla... },
 *   bundle_entity_type = "my_entity_type",
 *   links = {
 *     "collection" = "/admin/test/entity/collection",
 *     "canonical" = "/admin/test/entity/{my_entity}",
 *     "edit-form" = "/admin/test/entity/{my_entity}/edit",
 *     "delete-form" = "/admin/test/entity/{my_entity}/delete"
 *   }
 * )
 */
```

based on above, how do i load my entity in form below:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_entity\Form;

use bla...

/**
 * Form controller for the node edit forms.
 */
class MyEntityForm extends ContentEntityForm {
 //how to load my entity type here?
}
```

i tried a couple way but i keep receiving:

> Error: Call to a member function getEntityTypeId() on null

mainly because the entity is not loaded (null value)

this is how i create the route:

in my_entity.routing.yml:

```
route_callbacks:
  - 'entity.my_entity.routes::routes'
```

in routes:

```
public function routes() {
// Build Entity Create Route - CREATE
  $route = new Route(
      (substr($type->getRoute()['path'], -1) == '/' ? $type->getRoute()['path'] . $type->id() : $type->getRoute()['path'] . '/' . $type->id()) . '/create',
      [
        '_form' => '\Drupal\my_entity\Form\MyEntityForm', //TODO : not finish
        'entity_type' => 'my_entity',
        'bundle' => $type->id(),
        '_title' => 'Create ' . $type->getRoute()['label'],
      ],
      ['_permission' => 'entity admin settings']
    );
  $route_collection->add('entity.my_entity.' . $type->id() . '_create', $route);
}
```

if you see in my content entity type config above, i have:

```
 *   links = {
 *     "collection" = "/admin/test/entity/collection",
 *     "canonical" = "/admin/test/entity/{my_entity}",
 *     "edit-form" = "/admin/test/entity/{my_entity}/edit",
 *     "delete-form" = "/admin/test/entity/{my_entity}/delete"
 *   }
```

which i want those: edit, delete to be able to 'link' with my form as well - how to do this?

what i'm trying to achieve is: to generate forms based on field define in `my entity type`

Comment: How is your route defined? Please add your definition to the question.

Comment: Also the form class (ArmEntityForm) is not mentioned in the form handlers section of the entity.

Comment: Sorry the class in my php snippet is MyEntityForm it is typo. I have fix it, the route is generated based on links in contententitytype config

Comment: Please add the definition for the form route. I cannot help you if i can't see how you defined the route for the form.

Comment: Thanks @Eyal, I have updated my question above to explain how i build the route

Comment: Entity forms routes need to be defined with _entity_form: ENTITY_TYPE.OPERATION

Comment: Thanks @Eyal, how to define Entity forms routes with _entity_form: ENTITY_TYPE.OPERATION?

Comment: Isn't the Entity object already passed to the form constructor?

Comment: @kevin, it giving me NULL - which i think this is my problem, i can't understand, why it's NULL

Comment: Like Eyal said, instead of `_form` in your route, try `'_entity_form' => 'my_entity.create'`

Comment: where is : `my_entity.create` refer to? I did: `'_entity_form' => 'my_entity.create'` and it return me error: `"The "my_entity" entity type did not specify a "create" form class."`

Answer (score 3):

Your code currently loads the form with the `_form` routing definition. For classes extending `ContentEntityForm`, you have to use the `_entity_form` notation instead. Here is an example of an '*module_name*.routing.yml' file:

```
kollektivhampel.pdf_erstellen_form:
  path: '/intranet/{my_entity}/something'
  defaults:
    _entity_form: 'my_entity.default'
    _title: 'Your page title'
  options:
    parameters:
      my_entity:
        type: my_entity
  requirements:
    _permission: 'some permission defined in your module_name.permissions.yml file'
```

The     `_entity_form` is composed of two parts: before the dot, you have the entity type id, in this example `my_entity`. Behind the dot, you have the name of the form, defined in the `handlers` section of the `@ContentEntityType` annotation. In this case, the second part is `default`, According to your question's code, this refers to `\Drupal\my_entity\Form\MyEntityForm`. You might not need the `route_callbacks` code, as a static routing directly in the yml file is probably enough.

For more details, see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/structure-of-routes.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look into [`core/modules/system/tests/modules/entity_test/src/EntityTestForm.php`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/modules/system/tests/modules/entity_test/src/EntityTestForm.php#n31) file.

And you can see that in the object that is an instance of `ContentEntityForm` it possible to get an entity object using `$entity` property:

```
$entity = $this->entity;
$entity = $this->getEntity();
```