# change an add entity route to a custom route in order to not use admin theme

Tags: entities, routes

I will start off by saying i have already studied these posts, to no avail:

[Overriding an entity add/edit form through alterroute](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/190267/overriding-an-entity-add-edit-form-through-alterroute)

[How to load my Entity in Entity form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/235249/how-to-load-my-entity-in-entity-form?rq=1)

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones

I am trying to alter my add-entity route to be not under /admin, as we want this form to use the default theme, not admin theme.

My module is 'project', my entity is 'project'.
Here is my route in the project.routing.yml file:

```
mycompany.project.add_form:
  path: '/mycompany/project/add/{project_type}'
  defaults:
    _entity_form: 'project.default' #I have also tried custom form_mode here
    _title: 'Add Project'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'add project entities'
```

I get the error: Call to a member function id() on string in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sfchapter6nov2/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityForm.php on line 363

Yes, this error has been documented before, with posts such as the ones above.  I believe my unique problem is because my entity has an entity type, ie a bundle.  The {project_type} is my bundle name.  The EntityForm does not have an instance of the entity, and I cannot find where to create it.

Help and suggestions much appreciated!
Mary Edith

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that now the route parameter is a string and so you generate the error. You need to upcast the route parameter to an entity (the config entity of the bundle):

```
  options:
    parameters:
      project_type:
        type: entity:project_type
```

More info https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/parameter-upcasting-in-routes

Comment: Thank you very very much, 4k4.  This information was in the other posts, but not in a way that enabled me to I understand how to use it.  I had tried 'type:project:city_project', using my bundle name rather than bundle type name.   I appreciate so much getting speedy answers on this site!!!!